# How to vertically fill data in SQL from different table based on the same ID match?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to create a new query that would get data from different tables based on a certain matching ID. Problem in my case is that table 1 contains  multiple matching IDs in the same column (IDs have historical values linked to them), whereas table 2 contains just a single row with that matching ID (and piece of data in the other column linked to it that I'm trying to pull based on this key).

How do I make this work, so that my query has particular piece of data that I'm interested in table 2 filled in (with same values) until the last row of matching ID found in table 2? Thanks in advance!

An example would be:

Table 1.

```
ID1 | Date
ID1 | Date
ID1 | Date
ID2 | Date
ID2 | Date
ID2 | Date
```

Table 2.

```
ID1 | Data_of_interest1
ID2 | Data_of_interest2
ID3 | Data_of_interest3
```

Return should look like this:

```
ID1 | Date | Data_of_interest1
ID1 | Date | Data_of_interest1
ID1 | Date | Data_of_interest1
ID2 | Date | Data_of_interest2
ID2 | Date | Data_of_interest2
ID2 | Date | Data_of_interest2
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `JOIN` will do:

```
select t1.col1, t1.col2, t2.col2
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t2.col1 = t1.col1
```